# Swift post request error 500

Tags: swift, post, swift3, nsurlrequest

Im trying to post a http request with parameters, the response is XML Formatted.
see: https://www.codepunker.com/tools/http-requests/64243-brrjq9t
now, when I try to code that im always getting the same error 500. what I do wrong?

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.nakdan.com/GetResult.aspx") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    var bodyData = "txt=מה קורה&usr=&pass=&ktivmale=false"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data,response, error in

        print(response!)
        if error != nil{
            print("error")
            return
        }

    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: Error code 500 means internal server error that points out to your backend so ask him whats going wrong may be the format is wrong.

Comment: it isn't an internal server error because I can access it through the link above

Comment: So you say your content-type is text/xml, but it isn't.  You're sending some sort of half-baked application/x-www-form-urlencoded (which you forgot to url encode the unicode)

Comment: Please check that URL is not loading in browser. Its showing server error.